# Does Spread Syntax create a shallow copy or a deep copy?

Tags: javascript, deep-copy, shallow-copy

I am extremely confused for days now regarding the true definition of a shallow copy and a deep copy.

When I read the mdn docs (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Shallow_copy) on shallow copy, it all made sense. The first paragraph clearly explains what a shallow copy is. The docs says

> A shallow copy of an object is a copy whose properties share the same references (point to the same underlying values) as those of the source object from which the copy was made. As a result, when you change either the source or the copy, you may also cause the other object to change too — and so, you may end up unintentionally causing changes to the source or copy that you don't expect.

I totally got that part. From my understanding, the below code example is the example of a shallow copy since changing either the source or the copy causes the other object to change too.

```js
let a = {
    food: "pasta",
    restaurantName: "myPastPlace"
}

let b = a

b.food = "hamburger"

console.log(b.food) //hamburger
console.log(a.food) //hamburger
```

So, the confusing part was that when I use the spread syntax to make a copy. Is this deep copy or shallow copy? Because for the first level deep, to me, the spread syntax(operator) is making a deep copy. However, the MDN doc says the spread syntax creates a shallow copy rather than a deep copy.

> In JavaScript, all standard built-in object-copy operations (spread syntax, Array.prototype.concat(), Array.prototype.slice(), Array.from(), Object.assign(), and Object.create()) create shallow copies rather than deep copies.

```js
let a = {
    food: "pasta",
    restaurantName: "myPastPlace"
}

let b = {...a}
console.log(b)

b.food = "hamburger"

console.log(b.food) //hamburger
console.log(a.food) //pasta
```

Comment: “for the **first level** deep” = shallow. “Copying” a reference by storing the same value somewhere new, like `let b = a`, isn’t usually considered a copy at all in JavaScript.

Comment: @Ry- Thanks for the comment, so let b = a is not making a shallow copy? Also, why is the first level deep considered shallow when it is not behaving like a shallow copy would do (changing either the source or copy causes the other object to change.

Comment: No, `b = a` is making a coreference, not a copy, except when `a` is primitive. For example, in your example, `a.food = "sushi"; console.log(b.food)` shows you that the object was not copied, you just have two references to the same object.

Comment: @Ry- Also, if let b = a is not considered a copy at all in Javascript, how would you make a shallow copy??

Comment: @Amadan but all the examples I've looked up, most of them give out examples like this for a shallow copy :( freecodecamp, youtube, etc.,
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/what-is-shallow-copy-and-deep-copy-in-javascript/
https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/copying-stuff-in-javascript-how-to-differentiate-between-deep-and-shallow-copies-b6d8c1ef09cd/

Comment: The geeksforgeeks link is stright up wrong. The freecodecamp link is correct, and you have misread it: `let b = a // this is the copy` is under the heading "Primitive data types"; non-primitive types (i.e. objects) behave differently.

Comment: @Amadan Oh I see it, it was under the heading "Primitive data types," so having the same references is not a shallow copy? let b = a is basically having the pointer, the same references. The freecodecamp says `"Now, if we make a copy b = a , and change some nested value in b, it actually changes a’s nested value as well, since a and b actually point to the same thing. Example:"` It says `"make a copy b = a,"` and also says `"In the example above, we actually made a shallow copy."` That example looks identical to mine.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A variable can contain either a value (in case of primitive values, like `1`), or a reference (in case of objects, like `{ food: "pasta" }`. Primitive types can only be copied, and since they contain no properties, the shallow/deep distinction does not exist.

If you considered references themselves as primitive values, `b = a` is a copy of a *reference*. But since JavaScript does not give you direct access to references (like C does, where the equivalent concept is a pointer), refering to copying a reference as "copy" is misleading and confusing. In context of JavaScript, "copy" is a copy of a *value*, and a reference is not considered a value.

For non-primitive values, there are three different scenarios:

- Coreferences, as created by `b = a`, merely point to the same object; if you modify `a` in any way, `b` is affected the same way. Intuitively you'd say that whichever object you modify it is reflected in the copy, but it would be wrong: there is no copy, there is just one object. Regardless of which reference you access the object from, it is the same entity. It is like slapping Mr. Pitt, and wondering why Brad is mad at you — Brad and Mr. Pitt are the same person, not clones.

```js
let a = {
    food: "pasta",
    contents: {
        flour: 1,
        water: 1
    }
}
let b = a;
a.taste = "good";
a.contents.flour = 2;
console.log(b);
```

- Shallow copy makes a copy of an object, but any properties that contain references remain so — resulting in coreferent properties. If you change either object, the other is not affected; but if you change any object that is refered to by a property, you will see the change in the other as well. In this example, you will see `b.contents.flour` is affected by the change in `a` (because `b.contents` and `a.contents` refer to the same object, `{ flour: 1, water: 2 }`), but `a.taste` does not exist (since `a` and `b` are objects in their own right).

```js
let a = {
    food: "pasta",
    contents: {
        flour: 1,
        water: 1
    }
}
let b = {...a};
a.taste = "good";
a.contents.flour = 2;
console.log(b);
```

- Deep copy copies each property as well, recursively, so that there are no coreferences — whatever happens to the original object and its properties, the copy is not affected. Here, both `b.taste` and `b.contents.flour` are unaffected by changes in `a`.

```js
let a = {
    food: "pasta",
    contents: {
        flour: 1,
        water: 1
    }
}
let b = structuredClone(a);
a.taste = "good";
a.contents.flour = 2;
console.log(b);
```

Note that at this time `structuredClone` is still pretty new; if any users are using older browsers, you might need to use a polyfill.

Comment: [`structuredClone` is standard](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/structured-data.html#dom-structuredclone)

Comment: So coreference meaning pointing to the same object. But in order to do that, you need to copy the reference to have the same references pointing to the object. Therefore, you need to do let b = a for b to get the same reference as a . Isn't this a shallow copy?

Comment: No. As I demonstrated, shallow copy is a copy of an object, such that `a != b`, but every property of `a` is copied to `b`. A reference has no properties, and the concept of shallow/deep does not apply to it — it is only capable of a primitive copy (which results in coreferent variables).

Comment: @Kaiido Fair enough, I removed the... reference... to standards :P

Comment: @Amadan Thank you, I now fully understood!!!! Oh man this feels so great because it was confusing the heck out me for the past few weeks. I've looked over countless amount of resources to understand this concept but most of them (I can confidently say more than 90%) use examples that resemble mine for a shallow and a deep copy.

Answer (score 1):

The spread operator allows you to make a shallow copy. To make a deep copy, use the `structuredClone()` method.

So in your case it would look like this:

```js
let a = {
    food: "pasta",
    restaurantName: "myPastPlace"
}

let b = structuredClone(a);
```

Read more: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/structuredClone

Comment: So is my example for a shallow copy wrong?
let b = a is not considered making a copy in javascript??

Comment: When you write `let b = a`, you are making a pointer to the same object as `a`. Meaning if there is a change made to `a`, that same change will be applied to `b`. This is true for all reference types. In JavaScript, functions, objects, and arrays are reference types.

Comment: Yeah, so let b = a creates a shallow copy since both a and b are sharing the same references. Is this right understanding? Almost 90% of the examples I see for shallow and deep copies give examples like this

Comment: I wrote out an example here: https://jsfiddle.net/jgorelik23/kjLxs6f2/4/ Let me know if this helps.

Answer (score 0):

The spread operator makes deep copies of data if the data is not nested. When you have nested data in an array or object the spread operator will create a deep copy of the top most data and a shallow copy of the nested data. lets take a look at what this means.

lets say I have an array c that looks like this:

let c = [1,2,[3,[4,5]]]

If we spread this data to a new variable (d):

let d = […c]

if we change d[2][0] = 5 it will also change C array as it is a nested array

now both C and D will look like [1,2,[5,[4,5]]]

Comment: “The spread operator makes deep copies of data if the data is not nested.” In other words, it does not make a deep copy?